# Is this the correct way of binding factory to controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory, angularjs-templates

I have the following code in my module:

```
.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, emailService) {
    $scope.emailService = emailService; // Good or not; if not, why?
    $scope.showed = false;
    $rootScope.$watch('showed', function () { $scope.showed = $rootScope.showed; }); // In case you wonder why I did this - I'm using this trick to prevent watch from firing twice, because that would happen if I remove the watch below and put its code here.
    $scope.$watch('showed', function () {
        if (!$rootScope.showed) return;
        $scope.selected = 0;
        $scope.primary = true;
        $scope.verified = true;
        if (emailService.emails.length == 0) emailService.load();
    });
    $scope.EmailSelected = function () {
        emailService.setCurrent($scope.selected);
        $scope.primary = emailService.emails[$scope.selected].primary;
        $scope.verified = emailService.emails[$scope.selected].verified;
    };
});

.factory('emailService', function($resource, $http) {
    var emails = []; // [{email: 'sample@email.dom', verified: true, primary: false}, ...]
    var selected = 0;

    function sendreq(action, email){
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/email/',
            data: "action_" + action + "=&email=" + email,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            return true;
        }, function(data){
            return data;
        });
    }

    return {
        emails: emails,
        selected: selected,
        setCurrent: function(curr){
            selected = curr;
        },
        load: function(){
            $resource('/api/email/?format=json').query({},
                function success(result) {
                    emails.push.apply(emails, result);
                });
        },
        add: function(email) {
            for (var e in emails) if (emails[e].email == email) return false;
            return sendreq('add', email);
        },
        remove: function() {
            sendreq('remove', emails[selected].email);
        }
    }

})
```

And this code in my HTML template:

```
<div ng-repeat="e in emailService.emails">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.selected" ng-value="$index" ng-change="EmailSelected()" id="email_{{ $index }}" name="email">
    <label for="email_{{ $index }}" ng-bind='e.email'></label> <span ng-show="e.verified">Verified</span> <span ng-show="e.primary">Primary</span>
</div>
<div><button ng-disabled="primary" ng-click="emailService.remove()">Remove</button></div>
<form novalidate>
    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="submit" ng-disabled="email === undefined" ng-click="emailService.add(email)" value="Add Email Address">
</form>
```

And I want to ask, whether I've correctly assembled the module and template because I'm working with AngularJS for the first time. Specifically, I want to ask if it's correct to bind the whole factory to the scope? Also if someone has more time he can look at the other code to see if everything is right or not. Feel free to write any suggestions about my code.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It always depends on particular case.

This way boilerplate wrapper methods

```
$scope.add = (...args) => emailService.add(...args);
```

can be omitted, as well as their tests in controller spec.

Another benefit is that it provides existing object for proper data binding and scope inheritance of scalar scope properties:

```
<parent-scope>
  <p ng-init="emailService.selected = 0"></p>
  <child-scope>
    <p ng-init="emailService.selected = 1"></p>
    {{ emailService.selected === $parent.emailService.selected }}
  </child-scope>
</parent-scope>
```

This certainly would not work as expected if there's no `emailService` object. This is particularly useful when controllerAs syntax isn't used.

There's nothing wrong with exposing a service to scope - if its API matches the controller scope. And this may indicate an antipattern if it doesn't - or if there are too many services that are abused like that.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to bind the entire service ? I do not see a need to that in your code. You are invoking parts of the service using the service handler, there is no specific need to put the entire service on scope.

Comment: If I don't do that then I can't call service methods (in my case `add` and `remove`) from the HTML template.

Comment: You can have handlers on the scope, that in turn call the service functions.

Comment: Why is that better than simply putting the entire service on the scope?

Comment: Scope is runtime stuff. Have only things that are of concern there.

Comment: Okay, so to summarize - I should make scope functions which are called from HTML template and when invoked are calling the appropriate service methods?

Comment: Yes. Thats only my opinion though.